# WhatApp Profile Pictures from Contacts

Tags: samsung, whatsapp-messenger, 9.0-pie, samsung-galaxy-s-8

I have a Samsung Galaxy S8+. I have a few contacts who have not set a profile picture within WhatsApp. Previously, it would automatically substitute their lack of profile picture with whatever picture I had set for them in my Samsung Contacts app.

Yesterday, I have wiped my device and upgraded to the latest Android 9.0 Pie Beta (build ZSAI) and I've noticed in WhatsApp, this no longer happens.

Despite the contact having a picture in my Contacts app, WhatsApp just shows a white person on a grey background.

I've looked through the settings and permissions. I can't see anything obvious, but I expect I'm missing something silly.

Any suggestions?

- Samsung Galaxy S8+
- SM-G955F
- Android 9.0
- Build number PPR1.180610.011.G995FXXU4ZSAI
- WhatsApp version 2.19.34

Thanks!

Comment: WhatsApp really does that? I mean it can substitute the user profile with the one in the contact app? I think you don't see profile pictures of contacts who don't have you in there contact list (if enable in their settings)

Comment: These are definitely contacts that have me in their contacts list (mostly my Mum and girlfriend :) )

It definitely used to do it before. It would only do it if the user did not have their own profile picture within WhatsApp... so it used to be WhatsApp profile -> Contacts profile -> Blank image, in that order.

Maybe it's an old feature that doesn't exist any more, but it was definitely working before

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp has removed that feature for some time now (i.e using the photo from phone contact). When you upgraded Android, you must have also downloaded the latest version of WhatsApp.